# Error Handling- Looping script for email generation if network down

Tags: email, error-handling, runtime-error, lotus-notes

I've posted here before under a different account name and thanks all for previous help.

I have a spreadsheet which extracts information from a Data Historian, to generate a report on the status of the factory which is then automatically emailed out via Lotus Notes to recipients at fixed time intervals.

Sometimes there may be network issues affecting either the factory DCS, Data Historian (Aspen), or Lotus Notes. This gives a run time error when the script runs. Usually all that is required is to end the script, wait a period of time, recalculate the sheet, and then re-run the script.

Was hoping somebody could advise what code to add to achieve this. All I really need to know is what code to write and where to insert it to end the script in the event of a run-time error, and then to trigger another sub-routine in which I can add an application.wait and application.calculate before re-running the script. I need the script to end and run a separate sub as it causes issues with multiple scheduled events otherwise which then ultimately sends out multiple emails.

I've marked the part of the script that usually fails.

```vb
Sub Macro6()
    Windows("Silo report 2 hourly.xlsm").Activate
    '    Range("A1").Select
    'Calculate all workbooks
    Application.Calculate

    'Set up the objects required for Automation into lotus notes
    Dim Maildb As Object 'The mail database
    Dim UserName As String 'The current users notes name
    Dim MailDbName As String 'THe current users notes mail database name
    Dim MailDoc As Object 'The mail document itself
    Dim AttachME As Object 'The attachment richtextfile object
    Dim Session As Object 'The notes session
    Dim EmbedObj As Object 'The embedded object (Attachment)

    'Start a session to notes
    Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

    'Next line only works with 5.x and above. Replace password with your password
    'Get the sessions username and then calculate the mail file name
    'You may or may not need this as for MailDBname with some systems you
    'can pass an empty string or using above password you can use other mailboxes.
    UserName = Session.UserName
    MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    'Open the mail database in notes
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
    If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
        'Already open for mail
     Else
        Maildb.OPENMAIL
    End If
    'Set up the new mail document
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument

    MailDoc.Form = "Memo"


    vaRecipient = VBA.Array("xxx.xxx@xxx.com", "yyy.yyy@yyy.com", "zzz.zzz@zzz.com")

    MailDoc.SendTo = vaRecipient

    MailDoc.Subject = Range("B1").Value

    Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

'**THE RUNTIME ERROR USUALLY OCCURS WITHIN THE NEXT 5 LINES OF SCRIPT**

    Dim notesUIDoc As Object
    Set notesUIDoc = workspace.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)


    Call notesUIDoc.GOTOFIELD("Body")
    Call notesUIDoc.FieldClear("Body")

    Call notesUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", Range("B9").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Range("b10").Value & Range("I10").Value & Range("D10").Value & vbCrLf & Range("b11").Value & Range("I11").Value & Range("D11").Value & vbCrLf & Range("b12").Value & Range("I12").Value & Range("D12").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Range("b13").Value & Range("I13").Value & Range("D13").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Range("b14").Value & Range("C14").Value & Range("D14").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Range("b15").Value & Range("I15").Value & Range("D15").Value & vbCrLf)

    notesUIDoc.Send
    notesUIDoc.Close


    MailDoc.PostedDate = Now() 'Gets the mail to appear in the sent items folder

    'MailDoc.Send 0, vaRecipient
    'Clean Up
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set AttachME = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In LotusScript as well as in Visual Basic / VBA the error handling works exact the same. At the beginning of your Script you define where to go if an error occurs:

```vb
On Error Goto ErrorHandler
```

Place a Jump- Mark above the line, where you want to start over, when the error occurs:

```vb
TryAgain:
```

At the very end of your sub you define the errorhandler itself:

```vb
EndSub:
  '- prohibit that error handler is called without an error
  Exit Sub 
ErrorHandler:
  '- here you can react on the error, e.g. check for the err (Error number)
  If err = NumberOfErrorThatOccursWhenNetworkErrorOccurs then
    '- wait some time to give the network time to recover
    Sleep x '- put in x as best for your problem
    '- jump back
    Resume TryAgain
  Else
    '- another error occured: inform user
    Messagebox err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
    '- now jump to the end of the sub
    Resume EndSub
  End If
```

Of course this is a minimal errorhandling, and probably you would not want to jump around without further checks, but the idea should be clear with this example.
Just one more thing from the comments: you don't need the ui- stuff at all! Just omit it, as it is totally unneccessary and makes your code unstable.

Replace the whole paragraph starting with `Set workspace...` ending with `notesUIDoc.close` with two lines of code:

```vb
Call Maildoc.ReplaceItemValue( "Body", Range("B9").Value ..... )
Call Maildoc.Send( False )
```

Then you don't have to take care if something goes wrong - the document will just be discarded when the code runs again or ends, and it will be much more stable than handling ui windows and the screen will not flicker...

Comment: Thanks Torsten. I'll build that in and see how I go. If the sleep / resume option works it should be pretty much hastle free. Otherwise I might set it up to send me a simple email letting me know there's network issues (runs on a VM so half the problem is that I don't know its crashed till one of our 3rd parties calls up).  One more question if you don't mind- Can I add something to close the current active email draft? It will often populate the recipients and subject line, then hang up populating the body. I'd like to close that partial draft before it attempts to generate a new one.

Comment: Why do you do the frontend- stuff? Just write `call Maildoc.ReplaceItemValue( "Body", Range("B9").value .... )` and `Call Maildoc.Send(False)` and delet everything from Dim uidoc until uidoc.close

Comment: Forgot to notify you in my previous comment. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahhhh..... just realised I'd only read the first half of your reply before. Early start today and was clearly in need of a coffee. Amending the script now as per all your recommendations. Pretty confident this should fix most of it. I'm still very much at the copy/paste/ammend stage of coding, thanks for your help.

Comment: I just added that second part yesterday... You couldn't have seen it before as it simply was not there...